# how to plot stdin from terminal?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bunch of binaries that output data like this:

```
-0.002019
-0.000790
0.000158
0.001539
```

It's just a bunch of numbers that I want to plot on a y-axis with equal spacing in the x-axis.

The output is actually a couple thousand lines long.

I need a simple way of piping this to something that plots it, like so:

```
./program_dumping_numbers | ??? # a simple window of the plot pops up!
```

Comment: Take a look at [Gnuplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following:

```
./program_dumping_numbers | gnuplot -p -e 'plot "/dev/stdin" using 0:1 with lines'
```

where 0 is virtual line number, 1 is column number, "with lines" means that continues line instead of just points

Comment: hey, you forgot a ' there! :) but this is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I would highly recommend [ttyplot](https://github.com/tenox7/ttyplot), you can build live graphs directly in the terminal, reading data from STDIN

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here are some options. I liked `datadash` the best. None of them work that well.

`ttyplot`

```
datadash --average-line # install: https://github.com/keithknott26/datadash/issues/5
```

```
feedgnuplot --stream --terminal 'dumb 120,30' --lines # outputs new plots instead of updating the creen.
# `gnuplot -e 'set terminal'` for a list of outputs
```

```
asciigraph -r # usable but no stats and wrong height detection. No fixed scale. github.com/guptarohit/asciigraph/cmd/asciigraph
```

Answer (score 2):

An old way to do it is with plotutils <sup>[[1](https://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/)]</sup> installed.
(under Ubuntu  you can install with `sudo apt-get install plotutils`).

With the command

```
./program_dumping_numbers | graph -T X
```

it will plot your data in an X windows, instead with

```
./program_dumping_numbers | graph -T png > Myfile.png
```

it will create a png file.
Type `info plotutils` for further references.

Of course you can use gnuplot with a script that read from the standard input and all the features you want. (select as file input  `"/dev/stdin"` )